# delphi search is fishy

Tags: discussion, search

guys, this is fishy.

the search for delphi question rises a set of answers that give the idea of : "do you realy want to do it in delphi? delphi is not going to be there tomorrow".

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delphi+observer+implmentation

well thats my opinion for the top 5 result meaning.

is there a way to fix this *if* you agree with me?

should there be a spell checker for the search as such in google.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `[tag]` syntax, the [`+` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/search) and correct spelling gets you better results, [I think](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+%2Bobserver+%2Bimplementation):

```
[delphi] +observer +implementation
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem with search. This is the result of two things: first, some users posting questions and answers that imply, with varying levels of directness, that Delphi is on its last legs; and second, other users taking an interest in those posts.

I don't ever interact with Delphi myself, so I have no comment on whether the premise is actually true.